# How to confirm if database has been created for MongoDB for ReactJS + NodeJS Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am following a tutorial and got the following set up:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/newdatabase', function(err, dbConnection) {
  db = dbConnection;
  var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
      var port = server.address().port;
      console.log("Started server at port", port);
  });
});
```

Just by defining the URL with the name of the database, does the database get created? Or would I have to go on the terminal and manually create it? How can I check if `/newdatabase` has been created?

Also, how can I access the URL on the browser? Why aren't they defining the port number after the `//localhost`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB will create the database on the fly, as soon as you interact with it -- try adding a collection / document to it.

As for the port, it's probably using the default port (`27017`) since you aren't providing one. You wouldn't typically connect to mongo through your browser, though. Attempting that results in this message:

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

Comment: Could change the port to anything? Also how can I view the database via browser? Thought it was possible by going to the databse URL. And is there a way to confirm the creation of the database like on the terminal?

Comment: I think they [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) the built in http interface. There are a lot of other ways to interact, though. If you're looking for a GUI, I would suggest Robomongo at the moment.

Comment: As for the port, you can change it to anything. You just have to make sure your connection string is using the same port that your [server is using](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/).

Comment: And (for my third comment in a row..) you can use the `mongo` cli and type `show dbs` to list out all databases. You can type `use databasename`, even when the database doesn't exist yet. It won't exist until you do something to it (like inserting a document).

Comment: Can't you view the database in JSON on the browser?

Comment: Not natively (at least not that I'm aware of) with the newest versions. Take a look at the first link I provided. Mongo lists servers / libraries which are capable of exposing the database over the web.

Comment: Got it. Appreciate the clarification. One more question, how is it possible that all I need to start up is the client server? Does the database server start automatically because it is connected to the client server?

Comment: The database *server* needs to be running first. If it is not running, then MongoClient.connect callback will return an error. Speaking of which, you should make sure that `err` in your callback is empty. :) It's possible that your connection to the server isn't even working.

Comment: Sorry a few more questions. What's typically the command to start the database server? Also in the tutorial all I need to do is npm start and all works. Could it be possible it starts the database server and client server? If not how is that possible. And lastly, what does the following mean?   `let filter = {};
  db.collection("bugs").find(filter).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
  });` . Thanks again

Comment: Link the tutorial, if you can. It probably assumes you already have mongo installed locally. You won't be starting your mongo server from inside node, it will be something separate. Follow the official [installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) to get it running on your local computer.

Comment: This is it https://github.com/vasansr/mern-es6 It just says `npm start`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121961/discussion-between-dvlsg-and-jo-ko).

Comment: Sorry but I lost the chat and was finally able to locate the comment again. Could we open up a new chat? Thanks again dvlsg!

Comment: Am able to see the chat!

Comment: Sorry but keep getting dropped from the chat. I updated it with new messages. Please take a look. Thanks dvlsg!

Comment: Checking to see if you saw my last comment. please let me know!

Comment: Took me some time to test out as you suggested. Updated the chat. Please take a look.

Comment: Turns out it had to do with how the middlewares are ordered. Thanks for the help all this time anyway! Accepted the answer